# MSMQ 4.0: Has the message queue size of 4mb been removed?

Tags: msmq

According to this document, MSMQ 3.0 can support messages only upto 4mb.
[MSDN Resource Management in MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811056.aspx)

I am unable to find a similar document for MSMQ 4.0. I was wondering if this limitation has been removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No change. This is an architectural limitation from day 1 throughout all versions (1.0-5.0).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages.aspx

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: Hi John, the blog post in turn links to the MSDN documentation I linked to in the question. I was wondering if there was an MSMQ 5.0 document that specifically states that there exists the 4mb limit.

Comment: That's easy. 
It's not here: "What's New in Message Queuing 4.0" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701784(v=vs.85).aspx). 
It's not here either: "What's New in Message Queuing 5.0" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759129.aspx).
Something as fundamental to MSMQ as removing the 4MB limit would be written across MSDN in letters 10 feet high.